# Python - Compare first item in sublist, if repeated, compare third item and pick lesser value

Tags: python, list, set, compare, sublist

So I have a list that has sublists within it.

For example

```
biglist = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Hello', 'Friend', '1.5'], 
['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'], 
['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4'], ['Purple', 'Greetings', 'Pal', '2.8']]
```

This is what I am trying to do...I want to iterate though this to do the following:

- For each sublist, read position 0.
- If there is another sublist with the same string at position 0, then read position 3
- Whichever number is lower in position three, delete the other sublist entirely and keep the sublist with the smaller value. Some times there are more than 2 sublists with the same position[0]

So, for my example list. I want to keep the 'Red' sublist, compare the two 'Blue' sublists and keep the one with the smaller numerical value at specific position 3, then also keep the 'Green' sublist. I have been messing around with set() but am a little stumped. At first I tried hashing it to where that 0 position (red, blue etc) was the key, and the rest of the positions were the values (as a list) but I got stuck and went a different route.

Desired result:

```
biglist = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], 
['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'], ['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4']]
```

To note: the list I am using is being passed on by a previous function.

I found this on another question, however set() confuses me a bit and I don't know how to further look into that third position or how to properly pass the list I've already created via another function before this one in the same script. When I run this while trying to pass the list on, I get nothing out.

```
def unique_items(L):
found = set()
for item in L:
    if item[0] not in found:
        yield item
        found.add(item[0])
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think both in the original list and desired list there should be comma between 'Hi' 'There', right?  Please edit accordingly. I am not allowed to edit as the number of changes is only '2' and not '6' required for editing :-)

Comment: Yes thank you I thought I edited it but must have only done so in my script.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would create a dictionary of lists with first item in sublist (color) as key and value would be the tuple (index of sublist in list, last item in sublist):

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(list)

# This for loop extracts the index of each sublist (i) and then
# assigns the contents of the sublist to variables, in this case
# we want the first item in the sublist to be the 'key', ignore
# everything in between and grab the last item as the 'val'.
# If the sublists have arbitrary number of items then you could
# use for i, item in enumerate(biglist) and replace key with
# item[0] and val with item[3]
for i, (key, *_, val) in enumerate(biglist):
    x[key].append((i, float(val))
```

x now looks like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Blue': [(1, '1.5'), (2, '1.2')], 'Purple': [(4, '0.4'), (5, '2.8')], 'Green': [(3, '0.1')], 'Red': [(0, '0.534')]})
```

Then I would create a new list by

- sorting the entries for each color in the dictionary, x, in ascending order so that the first item in the list is the item with the smallest "weight" value (what you called position 3
- taking the first item of that sorted list which is a tuple containing the sublist index as its first item
- finally retrieve the sublist using the index

So something like:

```
res = [biglist[sorted(val, key=lambda x: x[1])[0][0]] for val in x.values()]
```

`res` now contains

```
[['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'],
 ['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4'],
 ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'],
 ['Red', 'HiThere', '0.534']]
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! I originally had a dictionary similar but with the value as a list, not a tuple. Could you explain the for loop here? The "*_" confuses me. I am getting invalid syntax, so I assume something else needs to be in place of "*_". ***Actually I think I know why this doesn't work. There is actually an item in the sublists after the number. So for example technically red is really ['Red', 'Hi' 'There', '0.534', 'Another thing'], so it can't be a tuple due to there being more than  values. I will need all of those items for the sublist I decide to keep. Sorry I left that out!

Comment: Okay so I used defaultdict but differently and got this, now I will continue and update as I go on.

    x = defaultdict(list)
for item in biglist:
 x[item[0]].append(item[1:])

print x

Comment: I added some comments the code above. If your list contains arbitrary number of items, you could just change the way you're accessing the variables to the way you proposed. That's all you'll need to change. That dict is just so that we know which sublists we want to keep. The final result will contain all the data in the sublists you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach - I think slightly more readable

```
# result_list for verification
result_list = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'], ['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4']]

# original list 
biglist = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Hello', 'Friend', '1.5'], ['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'],
['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4'], ['Purple', 'Greetings', 'Pal', '2.8']]

another_list = []

import itertools

# Sort the big list by tuple of x[0], x[3] First sort by x[0] and then resolve tie by x[3]
biglist = sorted(biglist, key=lambda x:(x[0],x[3]))

# now group the list by the first element of each list, y gives an iterator, we simply make a list of that and take first element.

for x, y in itertools.groupby(biglist, lambda x:x[0]):
    another_list.append(list(y)[0])

# following line is just for verification
print another_list == sorted(result_list)
```

Note: here the order in the original list is not preserved. If you want that to be preserved, following should work

```
 result_list = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'],
['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'], ['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4']]
biglist = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Hello', 'Friend', '1.5'],
['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'],
['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4'], ['Purple', 'Greetings', 'Pal', '2.8']]

#print sorted(sorted(biglist), key=lambda x:(x[0],x[3]))
cleanup_list = []
import itertools
s_biglist = sorted(biglist, key=lambda x:(x[0],x[3]))

for x, y in itertools.groupby(s_biglist, lambda x:x[0]):
    cleanup_list.extend(list(y)[1:])

for x in cleanup_list:
    biglist.remove(x)

print biglist
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with another way I figured out, I will post it again so people can see it properly

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much everyone! This is how I solved it my own way. Maybe it is not the best way and I know my variables aren't named the best (I actually named them simplistic purposefully in this example, but for my real script they are specific and unique). The actual input list is from a file that is 50,000+ lines long.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict

biglist = [['Red', 'Hi', 'There', '0.534'], ['Blue', 'Hello', 'Friend', '1.5'], 
['Blue', 'Yo', 'Dude', '1.2'], ['Green', 'Bon', 'Jour', '0.1'], 
['Purple', 'Hey', 'Sup', '0.4'], ['Purple', 'Greetings', 'Pal', '2.8']]

x = defaultdict(list)
for item in biglist:
    x[item[0]].append(item[1:])

y = dict(x)

for key, value in y.items():
    FINAL = []
    if len(value) <= 1:
        FINAL.append(value)
    else:
        valuelist = []
        for version in value:
            valuelist.append(version[3])
            best = min(valuelist)
        for version in value:
            if version[3] == best:
                FINAL.append(version)
        y[key] = FINAL
print y
```